# How do you pass arrays between pages without a form in php

Tags: php, html, variables, multidimensional-array, continuation-passing

I have used multi-dimesional array from a database to bring back a row ($dataTotal) and another one to bring back a position in that row ($data['position1']) depending on if I want to display anything in the array on that first page

When the user clicks on a link, I would like the page to override the existing value of the  $data array, and pass that new value to a new page where I can display different positions of that same array. For e.g $data['position2'].

Page 1

```
 <a href="../webapp/pages/influencer/person.php?data=<?php $data =  $dataTotal[0]; echo $data; ?>"
```

Page 2

```
$data = $_GET['data']; echo $data['position2'];
```

My only problem is that it shows that Im passing a string with this link. So incompatible datatypes.

Comment: HTTP is based on GET and POST, so, since you are using a `a` tag, you can only do GET request, and so you must pass the parameters on the URL (or you can use cookie, thing that i would not suggest)

Comment: You can use the `$_SESSION` variable to keep values.

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you can use `serialize()` function to convert a array to a string and then encode it with `urlencode()`.
example:

```
<a href="../webapp/pages/influencer/person.php?data=<?php $data =  $dataTotal[0]; echo urlencode(serialize($data)); ?>";

$data = unserialize(urldecode($_GET['data'])); 

echo $data['position2'];
```